# Java: Runtime.exec to get Linux distro name

Tags: java, command, exec

I would like to check distro name, but I have got problem with bash executing command. Why this code works ok and print folder content

```
String cmd[] = {"ls","-a"};
Runtime run = Runtime.getRuntime(); 
try {
    Process proc = run.exec(cmd);
    BufferedReader read=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));
    while(read.ready()) {
        System.out.println(read.readLine());
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

But `cmd[] = {"cat","/etc/*-release"};` doesnt? It simply doesn't print anything, neither error nor distro. Ofc. it works in terminal. What is wrong with that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason it works in Bash is that Bash recognizes `/etc/*-release` as a glob and performs the necessary filename-expansion. `Process` doesn't do that; it just calls `cat` with the exact argument you specify. (In other words, you're running the equivalent of the Bash command `cat '/etc/*-release'`.)

One option, I suppose, is to actually call Bash and let it handle that for you:

```
String cmd[] = { "bash", "-c", "cat /etc/*-release" };
```

but I think it makes more sense to use the Java file-system API to search `/etc` for a file whose name ends in `-release`, and read that file's contents normally. (See [the Javadoc for `java.io.File`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html) and [the Javadoc for `java.io.FileReader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileReader.html).)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    String[] cmd = {
    "/bin/sh", "-c", "cat /etc/*-release" };

    try {
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
        BufferedReader bri = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                p.getInputStream()));

        String line = "";
        while ((line = bri.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`Runtime.exec` does not invoke the shell (e.g. bash), but rather directly launches the process.  When you type `ls /etc/*-release` in bash, bash itself is responsible for expanding the * into all of the filenames that match the pattern.  So when bash invokes the ls command, ls sees the actual filenames as arguments.  On the other hand, when your java code invokes the ls command, ls sees the actual string "/etc/*-release", which is a file that does not exist.

The easiest fix is to pass /etc/lsb-release.  A better solution would be to invoke `lsb_release -c`.